# MS Word Manipulation using Python

Tags: python, python-docx

I have ms word document and I want to apply the following setting automatically using python

1.Font type = Trebuchet MS

2.Font Size = 11

3.Table and Appendices font Size = 10

4.Line spacing = multiple of 1.15

5. Space before paragraph = 0

6.Space after paragraph = 0

7.Paragraph should be Justified

8.Number should be aligned to the bottom right corner of document

9.Text in the table should be Justified
10.Insert footer and header automatically
11.Tool should ensure that a document with a single page shall not have a page number. ,

12.Tool should ensure that For documents exceeding one page, page numbers shall be inserted at the right hand side of the document.

13.Tool should ensure that the cover page shall not be assigned a page number.

14.Tool should ensure that Roman numbers (i, ii, iii. .. ) used only on the preliminary pages including table of contents, preface, abbreviations, list of tables, executive summary

15.Tool should ensure that Arabic numbers (1, 2, 3 ...) used only for main text of the report and appendices.

16.Tool should ensure that  year in any document is written in full for the preceding year and two last digits for the current year. For example; instead of writing 2020/2021, write 2020/21

17.Tool should ensure that only English United Kingdom vocabularies are used and NOT English United States.  Example: "analyse -English UK" vs "analyze -English US".

18.Tool should ensure that Numbers presented in a paragraph that are less than 10 should be written in words (one, two, three ...).

19.Tool should ensure that Numbers presented in a paragraph For 10 and above, they should be written in numerals.

20.Tool should ensure that Numbers within the table must be expressed in numerals even if they are less than 10.

This is my code so far

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Pt
from docx.shared import Inches
from docx.enum.text import WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH
from docx.shared import Length

path = 'C:\\Users\\Gaston\\Documents\\Words\\test.docx'


doc = Document(path)



style = doc.styles['Normal']

font = style.font  
font.name = 'Trebuchet MS'
font.size = Pt(11)  

paragraph = doc.add_paragraph()
paragraph_format = paragraph.paragraph_format
paragraph_format.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.JUSTIFY
paragraph_format.right_indent = Inches(1)
paragraph_format.space_before = Pt(0)
paragraph_format.space_after = Pt(0)
paragraph_format.line_spacing = Length(1.15)

doc.save(path)
```

Comment: Hi, its a bit unclear from the question what help you need. Can you be more specific about the blocker you are facing right now?

Comment: My code does not return expected results, it does not apply styles to ms word document

Comment: @gastonedereck you're going to need to dig a little deeper to troubleshoot. Open the file with Word and inspect the Normal style. See if it reflects your changes. Also, inspect the text and see if they have some other style applied. Other styles will generally define their own character formatting that overrides `Normal`. Also mention what language the text is in. Cursive-script languages like Arabic use a different font setting.

Comment: My file does not reflect the style I applied, The text is in English